# Find the derived subgroup of $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Find the derived subgroup of $A_4$.

Since it is $A_4$, for a permutation $\sigma$ to be in $A_4$, $\sigma$ must have a cycle structure of $2$ cycles. Therefore, $\sigma=(ab)(cd)$.

The commutator of such elements, would be obviously another permutation of $2$-cycle (of length $2$).

Does it mean that $A'_4=A_4$?

Comment: The group of $(2+2)$-cycles of $S_4$ is not $A_4$. It's a proper (and, in fact, abelian) subgroup of $A_4$ known as Klein's subgroup. You forgot to include the $3$-cycles.

Comment: (of course, it's a group provided you include the identity)

Comment: @Saucy O'Path Oh dang, I really did forget it. This kinda ruins my solution, as the commutator of $2$ permutations with a $3$-cycle isn't a $2$ cycle... How can I continue?

Comment: The commutator of two elements of $A_4$ cannot ever be a $2$-cycle, because $2$-cycles are not elements of $A_4$. Whether or not the commutator of two elements of $A_4$ is a $(2+2)$-cycle is another story. For instance, the commutator of two $(2+2)$-cycles of is always the identity. The commutator of two $3$-cycles of $S_4$ is sometimes the identity, but more often it is a $(2+2)$-cycle...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider the Klein $4$-group $V$ in $A_4$, that is $$\{1,(12)(34),(14)(23),(13)(24)\}$$
It can be checked that $V$ is a normal subgroup of $A_4$.
Since $A_4/V\cong \Bbb{Z}_3$ is abelian, we have $A_4'\le V$.
Since $A_4$ is nonabelian, $A_4'\neq 1$.
Hence there exists a $(ab)(cd)\in A'_4$.
Since $A'_4$ is a normal subgroup of $A_4$ and every product of $2$ disjoint transpositions are conjugate in $A_4$, we have $$A'_4=V$$

There are a few results that are used here:
(i) If $G/N$ is abelian, then $G'\le N$.
(ii) If $G$ is abelian, then $G'=1$
(iii) Two permutations are conjugate in $S_n$ iff they have the same cycle structure.

Comment: Can you explain how "Two Permutations are conjugate in $S_n$ if and only if they have the same cycle type $\implies$ product of 2 disjoint transpositions are conjugate in $A_4$?

Comment: @Babai For example consider $\alpha=(12)(34)$, $\beta=(14)(23)$. Take $g=(243)$. Then it can be verified that $g\alpha g^{-1}=\beta$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputations to comment Alan Wang's solution.
But it should be checked that each factor of a 2 disjoint transpositions is actually single (i.e. odd) permutation which is not in $A_4$.
ex.) (1 2)(3 4) $\in A_4$, but (1 2) $\notin A_4$ nor (3 4) $\notin A_4$.

If (a b c)S = (a b)(c d) for some S$\in A_4$ then
S = (b c d) such that, (a b c) (b c d) = (a b)(c d) where
(d a b) (b c d) (d b a) = (a c b).
Thus, V < $A'_4$.
And, V > $A'_4$ since $A'_4/V\simeq Z_3$ is abelian, we have $A'_4 = V$.

Comment: No sure what you mean, but by definition, $(12)\notin A_4$ and $(34)\notin A_4$.