# General way of finding the commutator subgroup of A4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The title essentially says it all.

Is there a way of efficiently finding the commutator subgroup of $A_4,$ and groups in general?

I know that the commutator subgroup must be normal in $A_4.$

I know the conjugacy classes are classes of cycle type:

$1$

$2, 2$

$3, 1$

The normal subgroups must be a union of the conjugacy classes. Does this mean that the commutator is:

e+conjugacy class of cycle type $(2, 2)$+ conjugacy class of cycle type $(3, 1),$

where e is the identity element of $A_4$?

Please make the explination as simple as possible, I'm having difficulties with abstract algebra.

Comment: List all $12$ elements of $A_4$. Then compute all $[\sigma,\tau]$ for different elements. For a better way see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882098/find-the-derived-subgroup-of-a-4/2882129). Along Wang's answer is exactly what you have started.

Comment: Thanks! Il check it out.