# Show that the alternating group $A_n$ is not perfect for $n \leq 4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I am working through an abstract algebra text and am stuck on a question. The problem statement is: A group $G$ is called perfect if $[G,G] = G$.  Show that the alternating group $A_{n}$ is not perfect for $n \leq 4$ (without using the fact that
it is solvable).

I think I'm misunderstanding the question. In the case that $n=3$ this makes sense to me because $A_{3} = \{e, (1 2 3), (1 3 2)\}$ but $[A_{3}, A_{3}] = \{e\}$ which is clearly not the entire group. But since $A_{1} = A_{2} = \{e\}$ and $eee^{-1}e^{-1} = e$ why are $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ not perfect?

Comment: Which text are you referring to?

Comment: The text is wrong, or else you are misquoting it.

Comment: For $A_4$ see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882098/find-the-derived-subgroup-of-a-4/2882129). The trivial group is indeed perfect. It is often assumed that $A_n$ is not trivial, as is for $S_n$.

Comment: Care to engage with the comments, Katie?

Comment: I agree this can be closed. As commentators noted it appears there was an error in the text and the link shared for $A_{4}$ was sufficient.